# ReactJS: Extract values from Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After some processing, I get an array of objects similar to this:

```
0: {key: 1}
1: {key: 0}
2: {key: 1}
```

I want to extract the values from each object and check to see if a specific value exists among the resulting list of values, for example checking for 0. Can anyone describe how to get all the values into a single list?

Comment: So what's the expected result? `[1, 0, 1]`?

Comment: map on the array. `arr.map(x => x.key)`

Comment: You could try [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): `[{ key: 1 }, { key: 0 }, { key: 1 }].some(({ key }) => key === 0)`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want as a result—should it be a single value or the entire object, and do you want it in an output array? It would be excellent if you also posted your anticipated results.

Comment: @Unmitigated - yes, that is the expected result.

Comment: @alphatango165 `Array#map` does the job then: `arr.map(o => o.key)`

Comment: can you show us your array object data?(*arr=[{...},{...}])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understood there's several ways to do this.
But there's a few things you want to achieve and you can do them this way:

1. Get a new list with the object's values:
   `const newList = myArray.map(x => x.key)`
2. Now that you have the newList, depends on what you want to do, do you want to:

a. Just want to check if a value exists? `newList.includes(value)` returns true or false

b. Get the index of the first coincidence? `newList.indexOf(value)` returns the index or -1 in case the item doesn't exist in the array

c. Get how many times the value appears in the array?
In this case a simple for loop will do fine:

```
    let coincidences = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < myList.length; i++){
      if (myList[i] === expectedValue){
        coincidences += 1;
      }
    };
```

And many more things you can do with the new array:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Hope you find it useful.